# Plotting Landsat8 RGB image in R

Tags: raster, r, landsat, rgb

I want to plot a RGB image of Landsat8 in R.
Therefore I use GGE (rgee) and save one image locally. Finally I want to plot the image as a RGB image. But no mather what band combinations I use, the plotted raster is not RGB. What am I doing wrong?

Here I specify the parameters for the EE query (only bands of the visible spectrum):

```
AOI_bbox <- sf_as_ee(AOI_bbox)
time <- c("2018-05-01", "2018-06-30")
cc_max <- 5
# image collection
LS8 <-  ee$ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2") $
  filterDate(time[1], time[2])$
  filterBounds(AOI_bbox)$
  filter(ee$Filter$lt("CLOUD_COVER",cc_max))$
  select("SR_B2","SR_B3","SR_B4")
```

Choosing only first image of the image collection, clip it to the AOI and create 'RasterStack' from it.

```
scene <- LS8$first()$clip(AOI_bbox)
rast <- ee_as_raster(scene)

> rast
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 759, 746, 566214, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 417405, 439785, 4422555, 4445325  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=34 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : SR_B2, SR_B3, SR_B4
```

Rescale values of the bands to 0-255:

```
rast8b <- calc(rast, fun=function(x){((x - min(x)) * 255)/(max(x)- min(x)) + 0})

> rast8b
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 759, 746, 566214, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 417405, 439785, 4422555, 4445325  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=34 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : SR_B2, SR_B3, SR_B4 
min values :     0,     0,     0 
max values :   255,   255,   255
```

Plot the 'RasterBrick' (after rescaling) as RGB specifing the RGB bands correctly:

```
plotRGB(rast8b,r=3,b=2,g=1,axes=TRUE)
```

The result look like this and is not the RGB image. Why that?
[image: final raster visualisation that should be RGB]

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am wrong, but I'm quite certain RGB is Band's 4-3-2 respectively. 2-3-4 is not a true color stack but more-so for vegetation and water highlighting, which makes sense looking to your stack.

Here are the composite band classifications for LANDSAT 8 TIRS 2: https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-8

I would try 4-3-2, I haven't used much R so I won't try to debug your code, but looks good at face value.

Comment: The bands I downloaded are bands 2,3,4 (specified in the GEE query). Afterwars when plotting the data, the order of the bands in the raster brick is set to 3rd band (B4 Landsat), 2nd band (B3 Landsat) and 1rst band (B2 Landsat).